# Unity AdMob Plugin version 2.3.1 and Unity Google Play Game Plugin 0.9.30 doesn't work together

Tags: android, plugins, unity-game-engine, admob, google-play-games

I'm having a problem when trying to use both the latest AdMob plugin with the latest Google Play Games plugin concurrently. They work by themselves - I've tested this and ads show up if I'm only using the AdMob plugin and I can sign-in and view leaderboards/achievements when only using the Google Play plugin.

I tried using an older build of Google Play plugin (GooglePlayGamesPlugin-0.9.21) that was included in the repository - Admob worked but not Play Services. I used the latest plugin of Google Play (GooglePlayGamesPlugin-0.9.30) - Play Services worked but Admob would crash the application if any of the methods were called.

I noticed that the latest Google Play plugin would automatically delete my google-play-services_lib from the Plugins\Android folder. Per Google's instructions, this library is still required for AdMob to function. So why would their other plugin automatically delete this folder?

I investigated further and found the method deleting the folder at Assets\GooglePlayGames\Editor\GPGSUpgrader.cs but commenting it out just caused additional errors

```
                // remove the massive play services client lib
            string clientDir = "Assets/Plugins/Android/google-play-services_lib";
            GPGSUtil.DeleteDirIfExists(clientDir);
```

The author seems to be purposely deleting folder to keep apk size down. These are the errors I'm receiving:

> Error: [Temp/StagingArea/AndroidManifest-main.xml, /Users/User/Documents/myCStuff/GAMES FOLDER/MyNewGame/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/play-services-ads-8.4.0/AndroidManifest.xml:10] Trying to merge incompatible /manifest/application/activity[@name=com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity] element:

Can anyone assist from here?

Comment: Same problem for me I solve it by changing the ad network :D. There is an issue about google play service and admob. You can follow the updates from here. https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-unity/issues/149.

Comment: This is crazy... Google Play Games update to 0.9.30 was just a few days ago. From all the threads I've been reading, they had this issue for months. I just want a work around with AdMob, if they don't have a real fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I've been able to successfully use the latest Admob (2.3.1) and the latest Google Play Services plugin (0.9.30). I started fresh by deleting my old Assets\GoogleMobileAds, Assets\GooglePlayGames, and the entire Assets\Plugins folder. Then Assets --> Refresh
2. I imported the GooglePlayGamesPlugin-0.9.30 then GoogleMobileAds plugin (but I'm sure the order doesn't matter). It will recreate the folders
3. There is no need to copy any aar files from the android sdks folder as the author has created the GooglePlayGames Plugin to automatically create the play-services-ads-8.4.0.aar file in the Assets\Plugins folder.
4. Look for GPGSDependencies.cs in Assets\GooglePlayGames\Editor. Edit the script and add this line to the bottom:

> // Google Play Services
>             svcSupport.DependOn("com.google.android.gms",
>                 "play-services-ads",PluginVersion.PlayServicesVersionConstraint);

5. Edit the AndroidManifest.xml in Assets\Plugins\Android\GoogleMobileAds\Plugin by removing everything between `<application>` and `</application>`:

and replacing with:

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID" android:value="\ YOUR_APP_ID"/>
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.appstate.APP_ID" android:value="\ YOUR_APP_ID"/>
```

YOUR_APP_ID being the ID found in your Google Play Developer Console under the name of your Game in Game Services.Tested and Signing in to GPGS is functioning, as well as viewing leaderboards, achievements, posting and of course interstitial and banner ads.

Answer (score 3):

I am using Google Play Games 0.9.30 and Google mobile ads plugin 2.2.1. They both working fine together.

First import GPG plugin and run a setup. Then import Admob plugin and copy play-services-ads-8.4.0.aar from android sdk

```
sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services-ads/8.4.0/play-services-ads-8.4.0.aar
```

to Assets/Plugins/Android folder.

[image]

Next open Android manifest from *Assets/Plugins/Android/GoogleMobileAdsPlugin/AndroidManifest* and comment the following lines

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
<activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
   android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>
```

Now i am able to successfully test Interstitial Ads and GPGS.

Comment: See my solution above. Works with the latest Admob and GPGS plugins as of this writing.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Google is a gesture.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can try https://github.com/unity-plugins/Unity-Admob,
it contain gps,you not need add extra gps,version conflict may not exit.